# Como fazer esta operação simples retornar true?

Tags: javascript, operadores

Vi uma postagem e fiquei confuso: 0.2 + 0.4 == 0.6 retornava false. Como fazer para que esta operação de soma seja realmente igual a 0.6?

Comment: Isto se deve ao fato de que tais números quando representados na forma binária de ponto flutuante não dão um valor exato mas sim dízimas periódicas, o que faz com que a soma não seja exatamente igual. Os tipos de dados float e double são inerentemente imprecisos e só devem ser utilizados se sua aplicação pode conviver com tais imprecisões. Uma possível forma de contornar, além de empregar outro tipo de dado, é utilizar as funções de arredondamento.

Comment: Melhor consultar os *links* das perguntas duplicatas. Aqui está cheio de informações incorretas ou superficiais.

Comment: @anonimo é justamente as dízimas periódicas que não podem ser representadas no ponto flutuante, limitando-se ao tamanho utilizado e, portanto, sempre serão truncadas, alterando o valor representado. Acredito que você tenha se confundido no seu comentário.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É retornado false por causa do ponto flutuante. Javascript utiliza uma representação de ponto flutuante com 64-bit, ele basicamente te dá um valor aproximado, então:

Para `0.1` no padrão de formato `binary64`, a representação seria:

- `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625` em decimal

Então as constantes `0.2` e `0.4` em seu programa, são valores aproximados. A soma de `0.2` e `0.4` acaba sendo maior que o número racional `0.6` e, portanto, discorda da constante em seu código.

Comment: A sua explicação é muito boa, qual seria a proposta para solucionar essa operação de igualdade? `toFixed`?

Comment: `toFixed()` é uma boa maneira de se resolver isso, eu faria dessa forma:
`(0.2 + 0.4).toFixed(1) == 0.6`